# simple click event work with touchscreen device with Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, ubuntu, touch

I want to develop web app for koisk. i want to know that all click event and drag and drop events of jquery-ui is working with touch devices?
if they are not working then which is the best way to do this?
Please let me know if anyone having any idea for this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jquery UI` does not support touch events as of now. But you can use plugins like [touchpunch](http://touchpunch.furf.com) to make it work with touch.

All you have to do is include the library after `query` and `jQuery UI` like

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It will also work with swipe and pinch ?

Comment: @priyankapatel none of the `jquery ui` widgets are based on swipe and pinch. Your question specifically says click event and drag and drop events of jquery-ui. Some plugins like `jquery mobile` or `hammer.js` calculate the time delay, distance etc between native events and trigger custom `gesture` events. There is no such inbuilt events in browser.